# Bootstrap Multiselect showing 0 selected even if i select multiple values

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, css

When I select multiple values it is showing `0` selected in the label. I think there is something wrong with the Javascript. Take a look at this image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/5Dxwt5gvuE277Uyw9

I also want to store all the values in my database. Should I store all the values in an array and then pass it to PHP?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#multifield1 option:selected").each(function() {
    console.log(this.text);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">


<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Area of Interest:</strong>
    <select id="multifield1" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
      <option value="X">X</option>
      <option value="Y">Y</option>
      <option value="Z">Z</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You haven't included jquery.js in the page, which bootstrap relies on. `Should I store all the values in an array and then pass it to PHP?` if you're sending the request using AJAX then yes. If you're just sending a normal form POST then you don't need to worry about it as it will be taken care of for you

Comment: Take a look at [the function on this page on the jquery docs](https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) You need to add a change function to your js

Comment: Thanks i will look into the docs. but i am stucked in the multiselect option where the label value is not updated as i select multiple values it's still showing 0 selected. any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [onChange](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-multiple) event handler:

```js
$('#multifield1').multiselect({
    onChange: function(option, checked) {
        var selectedItems = $("#multifield1 option:selected").length;
        console.log('selected items: ' + selectedItems);
    }
});

$('button.btn.btn-info').on('click', function(e) {
    var selectedItems = $("#multifield1 option:selected").length;
    console.log('Info btn: selected items: ' + selectedItems);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">

<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <strong>Area of Interest:</strong>
        <select id="multifield1" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="X">X</option>
            <option value="Y">Y</option>
            <option value="Z">Z</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code is placed in your `$(document).ready` event handler, meaning it will only execute when the page is first loaded. And I assume that initially on page load, nothing is selected yet.

You could listen for the select's `onchange` event and use your code inside the handler, so that the code runs every time the select values are changed.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#multifield1").on("change", function() {
      $(this).find("option:selected").each(function() {
        console.log(this.text);
      });
    })

});
```

Comment: Ok, it's showing in the log, but even if i select multiple values it is showing 0 selected.

Comment: @ShadabEqbal *What* exactly is still showing 0 selected?

Comment: In multiselect when i am selecting multiple options the label have to be updated according to the number of items i have selected but whatever i am selecting it still showing 0 option selected  however internally it is selected and also values are getting posted in database. check out this image: https://photos.app.goo.gl/5Dxwt5gvuE277Uyw9

Comment: @ShadabEqbal oh okay, now I understand. If you want, include the image in the question so that others can better understand your issue. I myself have no better answer sadly.

Answer (score 0):

To send values in an array to PHP you should set "name" attribute of your select tag like this:

```
<select name="test[]" id="multifield1" class="multiselect-ui form-control" multiple="multiple">
```

Also, don't forget to make your form in a  tag and add a submit button.